# How do I set minSdk to 20?

Tags: flutter, dart, package, build.gradle, android-min-sdk

I ran into an error here

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Ayool\Downloads\src\instagram_flutter\googlemapsapi\gmaps_api\hope_google_maps_api\mapsgoogleapi\gmapsapi\android\app\build.gradle' line: 48

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Cannot get property '20' on null object

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

So I tried setting minSdk to 20

```
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.gmapsapi"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdk 20 
        targetSdk flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

But this error message pops up: "You don't have an extension for debugging Grade. Should we find
a Gradle extension in the Marketplace?"

Comment: The message about extension is just a suggestion from the IDE and not related to the error

Comment: Do you know how I can get a gradle extension then?

Answer (score 0):

Change it like this one -

```
defaultConfig {
     // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
     applicationId "com.example.gmapsapi"
     // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
     // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
     minSdkVersion 20 // Update here!
     targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
     versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
     versionName flutterVersionName
}
```